# Load FXML Files in Anchorpane

Tags: java, javafx, java-20

I Have a Main Anchorpane. Inside this anchorpane I have a Splitpane and inside this splitpane there is two Anchorpane(masterAnchorpane and sidebarAnchorpane). So I want to load rest of my FXML files in masterAnchorpane [IMAGE ATTACHED FOR REFERENCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCuX6.png).
I tried so many solutions in this case, but I can't solve this issue.

This is my code. Also I try many of codes to solve this.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXML/CRM/Customer/customerMaster.fxml"));
                anchrMaster = loader.load();
                CustomerMasterController cmc = loader.getController();
                scene_customer = new Scene(anchrMaster);
                stage_customer.setScene(scene_customer);
                stage_customer.setResizable(false);
                cmc.setStage(stage_customer);
                stage_customer.show();
```

Error Shows in this code

```
class javafx.scene.control.SplitPane cannot be cast to class 
javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane (javafx.scene.control.SplitPane is in module 
javafx.controls@20 of loader 'app'; javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane is in 
module javafx.graphics@20 of loader 'app')
```

So please help to solve this issue.
I'm a newbie in java and also there is limited references for Javafx20.
Thanks for Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preface:**

Your code/stacktrace looks like `anchrMaster` is an `AnchorPane` and you are loading a `SplitPane` into it.

The method `loader.load()` loads the fxml file and returns a node of the root tag of the fxml file.

I suggest, that your fxml file has a `SplitPane` as root node.

**Solution:**

Load your fxml file into a parent node object and replace the content of your `AnchorPane` with it.

```
Parent root = loader.load();
anchrMaster.getChildren().clear();
anchrMaster.getChildren().add(root);
```

Comment: it's worked. Thanks for your Answer

Comment: I have one doubt also, My Anchorpane is auto fit with screen size, So How can I achieve that the loaded FXML file fit with `anchrMaster`

Comment: You could try: stage.setMaximized(true);.

Comment: David, Your answer is worked. But its showing this Error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AnchorPane[id=anchrMaster]is already inside a scene-graph and cannot be set as root`. So please suggest.

Comment: Your exception text says everything about the problem. If you need more help, please create a new question in SO, so that others can answer too.